# Facebook Bot and Node: Empty req.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express

this is my first post on StackOverflow!

I have a problem with a new bot I'm creating.

First of all, this is my code in **app.js**

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import { VERIFY_TOKEN, PORT, MONGODB_URI } from './config';
import { botLogic } from './logic';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useMongoClient: true });

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Correcly deployed!');
});

app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  if(req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VERIFY_TOKEN) {
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
  res.send('Invalid credentials');
});

app.post('/webhook/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await res.sendStatus(200);
    await Promise.all(req.body.entry.map(async entry => {
      await Promise.all(entry.messaging.map(async update => {
        console.log(`Received update from ${update.sender.id}`);
        await botLogic(update);
      }));           
    }));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status('404').send('Nothing interesting here');
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('running on port', PORT);
});
```

I created the app on the Facebook Developer page and the webhook is linked:
[Facebook developer page: webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEf0Y.png)

If you go on https://my-personal-bot.herokuapp.com/ it should say

> correctly deployed

but If you go here

> https://my-personal-bot.herokuapp.com/webhook

is gonna say:

> Invalid credentials

and if I log `req.query` the result is an empty object.

[Logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf7Ft.png)

I built a couple of bots before and this initial setup was quite straightforward, however, I this particular case, I can't figure out where is the problem. The API version that I'm using is **v2.11**, it's the only difference with my previous bots.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

the body of the webhooks from Facebook is only json encoded, so get rid of the line that adds url encoding:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Also the request is encrypted using your app secret, so you'd need to decode that before using bodyParser.json()

```
app.use(xhub({algorithm: 'sha1', secret: process.env.APP_SECRET }));
```

of course you wanna set your env variable APP_SECRET in the heroku console

For a complete example usage of webhooks, look at https://github.com/mduppes/webhooks_test/blob/master/index.js